# Getting duplicate rows with row edit event in primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am Using Prime faces 3.5.8,I am getting duplicate rows with row edit event.I am getting my row count as fine but one record is showing twice instead of other.This I am getting when call my clintList to load.When I close dialog and open it it is fine,Even I checked my list It is getting right data,Thanks in Advance..
    My BeanCode for edit,

```
    public void onClientEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
        try {
            Client edtClient = (Client) event.getObject();
            if (null == edtClient.getClientName()
                    || edtClient.getClientName() == "") {
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
                        null,
                        new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                                CommonStringUtil.getUIString("clintNameEmpty"),
                                CommonStringUtil.getUIString("clintNameEmpty")));
                getAgencyClients();
                return;
            }
            HibernateUtil.beginTransaction();
            Agency tempAgency = agencyHome.findById(agency.getAgencyId());
            Hibernate.initialize(tempAgency.getClients());  
            HibernateUtil.commitTransaction();
            for (Client cl : (Set<Client>) tempAgency.getClients()) {
                if (cl.getClientName().equalsIgnoreCase(
                        edtClient.getClientName().trim())) {
                    log.debug("Client Name Already exists");
                    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
                            null,
                            new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN,

                                    CommonStringUtil
                                            .getUIString("clientNameExists"),

                                    CommonStringUtil
                                            .getUIString("clientNameExists")));                 
                    getAgencyClients();
                    return;
                }
            }
            HibernateUtil.beginTransaction();
            Client eClient = clientHome.findById(edtClient.getClientId());
            eClient.setClientName(edtClient.getClientName());
            clientHome.attachDirty(eClient);
            clientName = null;
            agencyHome.attachDirty(agency);
            HibernateUtil.commitTransaction();
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
                    null,
                    new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, CommonStringUtil
                            .getUIString("clientNameEditSucc"), CommonStringUtil
                            .getUIString("clientNameEditSucc")));
            } catch (Exception e) {
            if (HibernateUtil.isTransactionActive())
                HibernateUtil.rollbackTransaction();
            log.error("Error Updating Client Name", e);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
                    null,
                    new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, CommonStringUtil
                            .getUIString("clientNameEditFail"), CommonStringUtil
                            .getUIString("clientNameEditFail")));
        }
    } 

My View Part

<p:dialog widgetVar="clientDialogue" modal="true" id="clientdilogId"
        showHeader="false" style="padding:0;">
        <h:form id="clientDlgForm">
            <p:toolbar style="height:38px;">
                <p:toolbarGroup align="left">
                    <h:outputText
                        value="Edit Client Messages: #{adminAgencyBean.agencyName}"
                        styleClass="dialog-header-Text" style="line-height:38px"></h:outputText>
                </p:toolbarGroup>
                <p:toolbarGroup align="right" style="margin-left:50px;">
                    <p:inputText value="#{adminAgencyBean.clientName}" id="clientName"
                        maxlength="45" />
                    <p:spacer width="5"></p:spacer>
                    <p:commandButton action="#{adminAgencyBean.createClient}"
                        icon="ui-icon-custom-arrow" iconPos="right" value="Create"
                        style="margin-left:5px;margin-right:20px;" update="@form" />
                    <p:commandLink value="X" onclick="clientDialogue.hide()"
                        style="text-decoration:none;margin-right:10px;" process="@none"></p:commandLink>
                </p:toolbarGroup>
            </p:toolbar>

            <p:messages id="clientMsgs" />
            <p:scrollPanel style="width:980px;height:400px;width:100%;"
                mode="native">

                <p:dataTable value="#{adminAgencyBean.clientList}" var="client"
                    sortBy="#{client.clientName}" sortOrder="ascending" editable="true"
                    id="ClientTable">

                    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{adminAgencyBean.onClientEdit}"
                        update=":clientDlgForm:clientMsgs"/>
                    <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" />
                    <p:column headerText="Client Name" sortBy="#{client.clientName}"
                        style="white-space:pre-line;width:130px;">
                        <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output">
                                <h:outputText value="#{client.clientName}" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input">
                                <p:inputText id="editClientName" value="#{client.clientName}"
                                    maxlength="45"  style="width:90px"></p:inputText>

                            </f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Edit Client"
                        style="white-space:pre-line;width:80px;">
                        <p:rowEditor
                            rendered="#{adminAgencyBean.clientTransactionMap[client.clientId] lt 1}" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{commonmessages.NoEdit}"
                            rendered="#{adminAgencyBean.clientTransactionMap[client.clientId] ge 1}" />

                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Remove Client"
                        style="width:85px;white-space:pre-line">
                        <p:commandButton value="Remove"
                            rendered="#{adminAgencyBean.clientTransactionMap[client.clientId] lt 1}"
                            action="#{adminAgencyBean.deleteClient}" update="@form"
                            process="@none" styleClass="blue_button">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{adminAgencyBean.clientId}"
                                value="#{client.clientId}"></f:setPropertyActionListener>
                        </p:commandButton>
                        <h:outputText value="#{commonmessages.nodelete}"
                            rendered="#{adminAgencyBean.clientTransactionMap[client.clientId] ge 1}" />
                    </p:column>

                </p:dataTable>
            </p:scrollPanel>
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
```

Comment: You're saving to the database every time a cell is edited. This is huge overhead, you're better of just letting PF do all the work and then have a save button etc that calls your hibernate commit fucntions. Also after you do this you need to reload the UI to ensure it has the latest code that's been reloaded into the variable.

Comment: Thanks@VeenarM,I am unable to get your point,In my requirement I need to save the edited cell show the fresh list,that's why I saving every time.

Comment: Abstract your database layer from your UI layer, basically your datatable/cell edits will be automatic from PF componentry, ie when u do a change it edits the values on your datatable variable - ensure you get this working by just having a growl like message on row edit to show /old value / new value. then add a button that does your database 'commit' - basically you need to ensure that what you've saved is reloaded. It's hard to see with out your full files however.

Comment: thanks@VeenarM,I know It will automatically update the datatable,If I give null(Empty) in sting then I need to reload the list,It is failing there,Second one is If I give the existing name then we need to reload the list,so please consider these conditions also..

Comment: I don't know if its too late to answer, but I had the same problem and I've fixed it sorting the list in the query, i don't know why but when I set to the datatable the same list in diferent order (notice that in datatable you have order by client name ascending) the list show duplicated rows.

Comment: I've seen the same problem.   I'm pretty convinced this is a bug involving an interaction between row editing and sorting.   This is the second problem I've found regarding row editing interaction with other features (like dynamic columns, etc.)  So I'm starting to steer clear of row editors.

The suggestion to do the sort in a lower layer is a good one IMHO.